# Simple WP Query upcoming events with start OR end date

Tags: wordpress, events

I'm working with an upcoming events list. I create a custom post type, with a custom field: event_start_date. I also have some multiday extension events, defined by an additional custom field: event_end_date .

I have a code that work fine for events with a start_date later than today. But I fail incorporating the end_date condition. I try with a meta_query, with OR relation, that currently don't work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'event_start_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
         'relation' => 'OR',
          array('key'  => 'event_start_date',
              'value' => date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1 day')),
              'compare' => '>='),

              array('key'  => 'event_end_date',
                  'value' => date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1 day')),
                  'compare' => '>=')
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
// Rest of the loop
```

Thanks in advance.

**Note**: I have this other query, that works perfect selecting events with only a start date > than current date.

```
                    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'events',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'meta_key'  => 'event_start_date',
                    'meta_value' => date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1 day')),
                    'meta_compare' => '>=', 
                    'orderby' => 'event_start_date',
                    'order' => 'ASC',           
                    ); // The same loop and query
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually to order by a meta key the `meta-key` must be present in the query and use the `meta_value` as `orderby` value.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'meta_key' => 'event_start_date', // required to be used in orderby
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'  => 'event_start_date',
                'value' => date('m/d/Y'),
                'compare' => '>'
            ),
            array(
                'key'  => 'event_end_date',
                'value' => date('m/d/Y'),
                'compare' => '>'
            )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // orderby will use the value of meta_key
    'order' => 'asc',
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

Also you can use a type in your each array of meta_query as follows

```
array(
    'key'  => 'event_end_date',
    'value' => date('m/d/Y'),
    'compare' => '>',
    'type' => 'DATE' // to specify the type of the field/value
)
```

**Update:** You should use `date('m/d/Y')` and `'compare' => '>'` and make sure your date format is correct because right now it's in (month/day/year). `date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1 day'))` will show past dates too.

This should work if everything else is correct.
[Read Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: Thanks @Sheikh. I tested your suggestions but unfortunately, the results shows all the events list, including past events. I think the problem could be around the 'meta_query'.     -bless

Comment: Still not working, all events listed. I think my date format is correct, because I had started using other 'query' that works perfect only using start date. Just in case,  I attached above the arguments of this 'other query'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution not worked for me (mybe topic is too old for older versions).
For next searcher - solution to show all past events (with pagination)

```
  'post_type' => 'event', 
  'suppress_filters' => false,
  'meta_key'  => '_eventorganiser_schedule_last_start', // OR _eventorganiser_schedule_start_start OR ..._start_finish OR ..._last_finish
  'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today')),
  'meta_compare' => '<', 
  'orderby' => '_eventorganiser_schedule_last_start',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
```